# How to convert poisson probability into decimal only

Tags: python, poisson

I have below question. The average number of bouquets sold by a flower shop is 10 per day. What is the probability that exactly 15 bouquets will be sold tomorrow?

Display the probability only (in decimal).

I have tried this:

```
from scipy import stats
averagepass=10/24
probability=stats.poisson.pmf(15, averagepass)
print(probability)
```

but don't know how to convert this into decimal. I used round function but not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal"? What output are you getting and what are you expecting? Also, if you are using Python 2.X, `averagepass` will evaluate to `0`. Not sure if that's the root your problem

Comment: Hi there, output I am getting is 9.985635956943892e-19. I am using vim version. I am doing online assessment on my company's portal. So not sure which version it is.

Comment: Hi friends I got the answer. Actually it was calculation mistake from me. I took averagepass=10/24, but it is 10/1. Actually I consider one day = 24 hours. Hence, I take 24. Sorry for inconvenience guys.......

Comment: Answer for this question is **0.03472** and it is accurate. Here Poisson random variable (X) = 15 and average rate of success is 10 . Use online calculator in below link https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/poisson.aspx.

Comment: @RahulGaware, you've detailed what unexpected output you're getting in the comment above, but it would be helpful if you edited that into the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
from scipy import stats
averagepass = 10
probability = stats.poisson.pmf(15, averagepass) 

print(round(probability, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the f-string or 'formatted string literals'  (see e.g. [realpython.com](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) )

```
from scipy import stats 
averagepass=10/24 
probability=stats.poisson.pmf(15, averagepass) 
print(f'{probability:.25f}')
```

output:

```
0.0000000000000000009985636
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives you a very small probability which will always be rounded to 0.

Anyway, this is a way to turn a float to a decimal:

```
from scipy import stats 

averagepass = 10 / 24 
probability = stats.poisson.pmf(15, averagepass) 

print(format(probability, ".30f"))
```

output:

```
0.000000000000000000998563595694
```